# How to create dynamic content that doesn't disappear after reload (with jquery)

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am just planning on creating a portfolio website and before going any further I want to see if I can do this

This is a simplified example:

I have a button and on click I do this

```
jQuery('<div/>', {
       text: 'something'
}).addClass("test").appendTo('#left');
```

That works great,
However when the page refreshes it goes back (without showing the test class). How and what is the best way to create the whole website dynamically but where if the page reloads it would still have the test class on the page

thanks

Comment: You have to save it in a place. Database, file, cookie, HTML5 webstorage, what else you can think of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only ways is from :

- database
- a cookie
- a generated page (can be cached)
- via an ajax query to get the page "changes"

Keep in mind that the "changes" in your example are done from client side

Answer (score 1):

By far the easiest way to save content locally is with HTML5 LocalStorage.

You could save data to an object:

```
var prefs = {
    div1: {
        text: 'something',
        class: 'test',
        parent: '#left'
    },
    div2: {...},
    ...
}
```

and then save this object to localStorage:

```
localStorage.savedPrefs = JSON.stringify(prefs);
```

When the page loads, check this object and take action accordingly:

```
if ('savedPrefs' in localStorage) {
    prefs = JSON.parse(localStorage.savedPrefs);
    // change page based on prefs
    // e.g. alert('div1 text: ' + prefs.div1.text);
}
```

See:

- [W3C spec](http://dev.w3.org/html5/webstorage/)
- [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Storage#localStorage)
- [Good, human-readable overview](http://paperkilledrock.com/2010/05/html5-localstorage-part-one/)

Answer (score 0):

You would have to improve your 'dynamic' generated content by having it actually call back to the server (or set a cookie).

Calling back to the server would require use of anywhere from:

- cached page (saves a copy of the changes)
- database update (to keep the change for re-use)
- or setting your cookie

Answer (score 0):

there are two solutions to your problem:

- Use cookies
- use html5 local storage
- use the url (especially the things after the #) / address line
- db and other things: but they require server side support

I normally use the adress line, so deep linking will also work using the jquery Address Plugin http://www.asual.com/jquery/address/